# Mobile rotation to landscape causes iframe videos to render with smaller size

Tags: css, mobile, iframe, rotation

This has been happening for both Iphone and Andriod devices. The video renders using iframe well on portrait. But when I rotate the mobile to landscape it gets a smaller size.

[image: Portrait Mode (Its Fine)]
Portrait Mode (Its Fine)
But it get smaller size in Landscape mode

[image: But it get smaller size in Landscape mode]

Below here is a code screenshot
[image: Below here is a some code screenshot]

Comment: Is this an app you've written? A website? Can we see some code?

Comment: Hi, I have added a code screenshot. Sorry if that is not enough.

Comment: It looks like the `iframe` has its width and height set to 100%, meaning it will confine its size to the window. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: Yes it does acquire 100% width on portrait mode but its weird that after rotating to landscape it does not.